# "Error tokenizing data" when reading in a csv from a url in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, finance

I am trying to read in a csv from a url ([csv link](https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/)) then isolate the ticker symbols (AMLP, ARKF, ARKG, ARKK, etc.), but I am running into a problem just reading in the csv.

The exact error is: "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 3, saw 12".

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/")
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/", error_bad_lines=False)
```

If you just want to start from line 16 in the file (where AMLP is), use:

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.cboe.com/available_weeklys/get_csv_download/", skiprows=15, header=None)
>>> df
        0                                   1
0    AMLP             ALPS ETF TR ALERIAN MLP
1    ARKF           ARK ETF TR FINTECH INNOVA
2    ARKG          ARK ETF TR GENOMIC REV ETF
3    ARKK           ARK ETF TR INNOVATION ETF
4    ASHR         DBX ETF TR XTRACK HRVST CSI
..    ...                                 ...
610    YY           JOYY INC ADS REPSTG COM A
611     Z       ZILLOW GROUP INC CL C CAP STK
612    ZM  ZOOM VIDEO COMMUNICATIONS INC CL A
613  ZNGA                      ZYNGA INC CL A
614    ZS                     ZSCALER INC COM
```